# How to change address bar background color on intent ACTION_VIEW on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a facebook launcher like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://facebook.com")));
```

I want to change the address bar background color to R.color.facebook.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it using CustomTabIntent, if someone is having this issue what you have to do is implement the following dependency on AndroidManifest

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```

And use CustomTabIntent:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary));
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this,Uri.parse("https://facebook.com"));
```

The result is just what I expected :D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You are launching a third-party app, in the form of a Web browser. There are dozens of Web browsers for Android. The decision of what color to use for the address bar is up to the developer of the Web browser.